Woocommerce, variations on variable products share same stock
I need to have some of my product variations to use the same stock and so i created this function.
I use ACF plugin to add a custom field into my product variations, so i can gather them into a same group. And after a sale i use this function to update the stock of the other products that are in the same group.
Updating the stock works fine but i still have one problem.
This is my product structure :

Product A (Unique SKU) --> variation 1, variation 2 = group1 ; variation 3, variation 4 = group2 ... (groups have the same SKU as product A)
Product B (Unique SKU) --> variation 1, variation 2 = group1 ; variation 3, variation 4 = group2 ... (groups have the same SKU as product B)
Product C (Unique SKU) --> variation 1, variation 2 = group1 ; variation 3, variation 4 = group2 ... (groups have the same SKU as product C)

When i say same SKU i mean that all variations for one product have the same SKU. (The variations are size and frame color.)
But each product has a unique SKU.
I suppose it's not the best way to do it, but i already have 50 products and as many variations like this, so I would like not to redo everything from scratch.
That's why i need to add a SKU check in order to only update products/variations that have the same SKU.
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'update_shared_stock' );

function update_shared_stock( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product = $item->get_product();
        $product_id = $product->get_id();

        $group = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'custom_field', true );

        if ( ! empty( $group ) ) {
            
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product_variation',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'custom_field',
                        'value' => $group,
                        'compare' => '=',
                    )
                )
            );

            $products = new WP_Query( $args );

            if ( $products->have_posts() ) {
                $lowest_stock = PHP_INT_MAX;
                $ordered_product_stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

                while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
                    $products->the_post();
                    $product_id = get_the_ID();

                    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
                    $current_stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

                    if ( $current_stock < $lowest_stock ) {
                        $lowest_stock = $current_stock;
                    }
                }

                wp_reset_postdata();

                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'product_variation',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'key' => 'custom_field',
                            'value' => $group,
                            'compare' => '=',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => '_stock',
                            'value' => $lowest_stock,
                            'compare' => '>',
                        )
                    )
                );

                $products = new WP_Query( $args );

                if ( $products->have_posts() ) {
                    $total_quantity = $item->get_quantity();

                    while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
                        $products->the_post();
                        $product_id = get_the_ID();

                        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
                        $current_stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

                        $new_stock = $current_stock - $total_quantity;

                        if ( $product_id == $item->get_variation_id() ) {
                            
                            $new_stock = $ordered_product_stock - $total_quantity;
                        } elseif ( $new_stock < 0 ) {
                            
                            $new_stock = 0;
                        }

                        $product->set_stock_quantity( $new_stock );
                        $product->save();
                    }

                    wp_reset_postdata();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

EDIT : New approach that is cleaner and works for me.
I based myself on Misha Rudrastyh's code here:
website for the original code
And then I added the check to know if the variation belongs to a group or not.
To summarize, each product has its own unique SKU and the variations are grouped together into 'groups' via an ACF custom field (like before).
Each variations that must have a common stock are in the same group.
When an order is placed and paid for, the function searches the parent product of the purchased variation and see if it belongs to a group. It then scans all the variations of that parent product and if there are variations that belong to the same group it then updates their stock to match.
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_set_stock', 'variation_shared_stock' );

function variation_shared_stock( $updated_variation ) {

 $new_stock_status = $updated_variation->get_stock_status();
 $new_stock_qty = $updated_variation->get_stock_quantity();
 
 // let's get variation product, so we can get other variations
 $product = wc_get_product( $updated_variation->get_parent_id() );
 // getting variations, you can also use get_children() method
 $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
 $variation_ids = wp_list_pluck( $variations, 'variation_id' );

 remove_action( 'woocommerce_variation_set_stock', __FUNCTION__ );

 foreach( $variation_ids as $variation_id ) {

     if( $variations_id === $updated_variation->get_id() ) {
         continue;
     }
     
     $variation = wc_get_product_object( 'variation', $variation_id );
     $updated_variation_group = get_post_meta( $updated_variation->get_id(), 'custom_field', true );
     $current_variation_group = get_post_meta( $variation_id, 'custom_field', true );

     if( $updated_variation_group !== $current_variation_group ) {
     continue;
     }

     $variation->set_stock_status( $new_stock_status );
     $variation->set_stock_quantity( $new_stock_qty );
     $variation->save();

 }
 
 add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_set_stock', __FUNCTION__ );

}

Your question is unclear… What does mean "(same SKU)"? Is it that all variations from the variable product have the same SKU? Or is it each group that share the same SKU? Can you better explain this "(same SKU)" please. Note that in WooCommerce, each SKU requires being unique… Also, why in your code the lowest stock is set to PHP_INT_MAX? Try to better explain things, as it seems that your code is much more complicate that it should be.

Thanks for your answer, as you can see i'm new to this, it's a mix of a bit of wordpress knowledge, code i know, code i find online and AI. So it's really probably not the best and good way to do it. When i say same SKU i mean that all variations for one product have the same SKU. I sell photographs and the variations are size and frame color for the same photography that's why i keep the same SKU. Regarding the '''PHP_INT_MAX''' this is something from an AI. I'm sorry you must have so much wonky code like that with AI and noob like me.

This is much more complicated that you think, as WooCommerce Hold items stock on checkout and When an order is placed, it reduce purchased items stock levels (all this only if the stock is managed for the related purchased items)…

My recommendation is to NOT do this.  There's a lot of people who have poured countless hours into making WooCommerce work the way it does.  They've put tons of thought into how things should work and the way the stock and the SKUs work is set that way for a reason.  I recommend you just go and build out your products properly so you don't encounter a series of problems further down the road.

Thanks @TonyDjukic i'm just trying to understand in order to learn. There are many (paid) plugins to achieve what i want to do, do they work more in depth with the WC code? In my quick tests it works (with Stripe test cards) but if you tell me that it is a risk of problem i will not do it. The issue with my approach is more precisely where ? I need different SKU for each variation of the same product ? I sell photographs and i have multiple formats and  styles which gives me a large number of variations for the same product. As they are limited edition i need to have a shared stock.

That doesn't make sense though - if two of the products are different (because of size or shape) then they aren't the same, hence different SKUs.  I think, but can't recall for sure, that you may be able to manage stock on the parent product and not the individual variations.

@TonyDjukic yes i understand your way of seeing things and product but for me the product is the photo print, the rest are just options. I saw that it was not mandatory to add a SKU for variations : "SKU – Enter the SKU or leave blank. Note: If you set an SKU at the product level but leave it blank at the variation level, SKU will default to product level SKU." link

@tonarii thank you for mentioning my guide and I am glad it helped you! Recently I created a more advanced tutorial on this topic, maybe it will be helpful as well https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/variation-shared-inventory.html
